# What 's wrong for opening my new page?

Tags: php

I tried to create a login page in PHP. I have a problem with opening the new page when the username and password are correct.

All the pages are in the same directory, which is Inventory.

Here is the code:

```
<?
$serverName ="localhost";
$dbname="inventory";

$conn = mysql_connect($serverName,"root","");


if(!$conn) die("Connection error". mysql_connect_error());

else echo "connected successfully";

if(isset($_POST['login'])){
if(empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password']))
    echo "<script>
    alert('يجب إدخال إسم المستخدم و كلمة السر';);
    </script>";

else
{

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $username = stripslashes($username);
    $password = stripslashes($password);

    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);

    $db = mysql_select_db($dbname,$conn) or die("database connection error" . mysql_error());

    $query = mysql_query("select * from users where username = '$username' AND password = '$password'", $conn);
    $name = mysql_query("select name from users where username = '$username' AND password = '$password'", $conn);


    $rows = mysql_num_rows($query);

    if($rows == 1)
        {
            //echo $username.'<br>';
            //echo $password.'<br>';
            //echo '<br>'. "correct user name and password";
            $_SESSION['name'] = $name;
            header("location: C:\xampp\htdocs\inventory\menu.php"); 

            //echo "<script> window.open('C:/xampp/htdocs/inventory/menu.php','_self'); </script>"; 

        }
    else
    {
        //echo '<br>'. "incorrect user name and password";
        echo "<script>
        alert('اسم المستخدم أو كلمة السر غير صحيحة');
        </script>
        ";}}}

mysql_close($conn);

?>
```

Any suggestions about what might be wrong?

Comment: where's the HTML form that should go with this? check for errors, something you're NOT doing. and I hope this isn't intended for a live site (if so, **just don't**). and make sure you started the session

Comment: first no need to do two query because first select * from will give you all value, and second use `header("location: menu.php"); ` to redirect to other page

Comment: Dont use the absolute directory path in your header,for apache the root is  htdocs  `header("location: menu.php");`

Comment: sorry my friend, I didn't mean that but I tried it and not worked. maybe I have another problem in my  code since i am bigginer in PHP.